# Onchange event in Struts2

Tags: select, struts2, onchange

How to call action on onchange event with select option in struts2.

Here is my code and how can I integrate with On change event.

```
<s:select name="menuItem" list="menuItems" listKey="menuItemID"

listValue="menuItemName" headerValue="--MenuItems--"

cssClass="selectbox_bg2" id="select" />
```

Can anyone please provide an example..

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference in how you apply `onchange` or any other javascript event handler to struts tag as compared to regular HTML tags. [Struts2 select Tag Ref](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/select.html)

```
<s:select name="menuItem" list="menuItems" listKey="menuItemID"

listValue="menuItemName" headerValue="--MenuItems--"

cssClass="selectbox_bg2" id="select" onchange="handleChange(this.value)"/>
```

JavaScript

```
function handleChange(value){
  window.location="callMyAction?ValueToSubmit="+value; //or you can submit a form from here or make an ajax call
}
```

Or if you are using *jquery* then

```
$("#select").change(function(e){
    var value = $(this).val();
    //submit a form or make ajax call or use window.location
});
```

Comment: OK Thank you..so how we execute an action for that onChange event?

Comment: See the edited answer. you can submit a form or make an ajax call

Comment: Ok it's fine..And I have one more doubt how we get this parameter(value) in a struts2 action class??

Comment: For that you need to declare a variable with the same name as in jsp e.g. in `handleChange()` function I am assigning the value to `ValueToSubmit` variable, so in `callMyAction` action class you need to declare a variable with name `ValueToSubmit` and also its getter/setter

Comment: Nice answer. In my situation I have several <s:select>. How do you write the jquery handler in this situation? I guess you need to include the select id somehow.

Comment: @ThorHovden If your behaviour for all the `select` elements is same then you can assign a class to these elements using  `cssClass="myClass"` and then write a common handler using `$(".myClass")`. If the behavior needs to be different then yes, you have to define separate handlers