# Passing a parameter from JSP to action class in Struts 2

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I am trying to pass value of a text-field as a URL parameter from a JSP to an action class on clicking of a button(non-submit button) and have found a solution in this link: [Onchange event in Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948226/onchange-event-in-struts2).

I have followed all the steps mentioned in that link i.e.:

- creating a javascript function for `onClick` event
- inside the function i.e. `setDealers`, passing the value i.e. `"reportGroup"` to the action class as shown below

```js
function setDealers(){
  var rep_value=document.getElementById("reportGroup").value;
  alert("Value is"+rep_value);
  window.location=="getDealersByGrouppopUpAction?reportGroup="+rep_value;
  alert("Just a check")
}
```

- created a variable with name `"reportGroup"` in the action class i.e. `PopUpAction.java` with getters and setters for it.

Also to support all this, I have following configuration in `struts.xml`:

```xml
<action name="*popUpAction" class="popUpAction" method="{1}" > 
    <!--this will call a desired method present inside action class --> 
    ...
    ...
</action>
```

On clicking of the button, `getDealersByGroup` method of `PopUpAction` class is supposed to be invoked and use the passed value i.e. `"reportGroup"` in a SQL query.
But as per the above javascript function `setDealers` only alert commands are getting executed and the desired value is not getting passed to the action class.

Is there any thing missing/ or wrong with `struts.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have made a typo in code `==` vs `=`

```
window.location="getDealersByGrouppopUpAction?reportGroup="+rep_value;
```

Second, this sounds like redirect to the action, for calling action use [`s:action`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/action.html) or [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608251/573032).

Trird, for URLs better use [`s:url`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/url.html) tag to build the url.

```
var url = "<s:url action='getDealersByGrouppopUpAction'/>"+"?reportGroup="+rep_value;
window.location=url;
```