# How to have clickable table row send parameters to Struts action class?

Tags: javascript, html, struts2, html-table

I have a HTML table where each row is clickable. Here is how I have them clickable:

```
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
          window.document.location = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ActionClass";
    });

<tr class="clickable-row">
    <td class="text-left">some parameter</td>
    ...
</tr>
```

I am not sure how to pass the data from the clicked table row to the struts action since I am using a Javascript function to handle the click/navigation. In  the past I was able to use something like:

```
    <s:url action="ActionClass" var="actionLink" >
            <s:param name="param1">${param1}</s:param>
            <s:param name="param2">${param2}</s:param>
    </s:url>
    <s:a href="%{actionLink}">go to Action</s:a>
```

But I can't use the `<s:` tags inside the JS function. What is the best way to go about this?

Not really a duplication question. This was more specific how to get a table row parameter sent to an action by a clickable row. I was able to get a parameter to send by a column button, but never received an answer that helped with a clickable row.

Comment: The location should change if you click on the anchor tag.

Comment: @RomanC the location changes, but I can't pass the parameters of the clicked row to the action class. I am looking for a way to do this. O rare you saying the actual location = part should change to include the parameters?

Comment: The best way (in this case, for you) is to write normal JavaScript that uses `data-` attributes of the row.

Comment: @Seephor You should know how the parameters are determined. If they are determined on the server then you can use url tag or anchor tag to link the record, otherwise you get them from the code and concatenate to the url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a parameter from JSP to action class in Struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452365/passing-a-parameter-from-jsp-to-action-class-in-struts-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a column with hyper link that passes parameters to action like:

```
<td>
  <s:a href="test.action?param1=%{param1}><s:property value="param1"/></s:a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add a select button column that submits a form for the row the button is on.